# How do you write ListBox items to a text file?

Tags: c#, file-io, listbox

The title basically says it all. I am attempting to convert a ListBox in Visual Studio into a text file. I'm doing this in C#, as it is my most familiar language.

I would imagine that the code that I have would work, but for some reason, it does not. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\WhosTalking\List.txt");
foreach (var item in list.Items)
{
    SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Your logic is correct, but you need to close the stream after finishing writing to it. Add `SaveFile.Close();` at the end or better, wrap it in a [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). That being said, there are easier ways to achieve this. One example is: `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filePath, list.Items.Cast<string>());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow !

I just run a very simple example, and apart of making use of `using` as `StreamWriter` is a disposable object, all went fine ... I-m just wondering **if you have permission** to write to the `C:` drive, and as **TheGeneral** mentioned, you do need to close the file, hence I've use the `using` statement, as it does close and dispose the object in one go.

my simple example:

[image]

where the file write is:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter SaveFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\List.txt"))
    {
        foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
        {
            SaveFile.WriteLine(item.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
File.WriteAllLines("SomePath",listBox1.Items.Cast<string>());
```

---

[Enumerable.Cast(IEnumerable) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

[File.WriteAllLines Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Creates a new file, writes one or more strings to the file, and then
>   closes the file.